# Not able to loop through Excel sheet using Excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a simple macro to loop through all the sheets. However, it only applies to the first sheet. I've already read the other posts which have success so I'm not sure why my code won't work.

```
Sub Archive_Sheets()
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Range("B2").Value = "DONE"
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Range() refers to the ActiveSheet. If you want it to refer to a different worksheet, you need to qualify it: ws.Range()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must write you code like-

```
ws.Range("B2").Value = "DONE"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `ws.` at the beginning of said range. Otherwise, VBA will auto-complete `Range("B2").Value = "DONE"` to `ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = "DONE"`. But that's not what you want (I assume). So, this is what you should try instead:

```
Sub Archive_Sheets()
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("B2").Value = "DONE"
    Next ws
End Sub
```